# Retrofitting DXA publications to an existing BluePrint

Tags: 2013, dxa, blueprint, dxa-1.2

We have an existing BluePrint in our SDL Tridion implementation (just place holders for business).

While we import (install using PS) the DXA Publications, the installation defaults to the Publications `000 Empty`, `100 Master` and `400 Example Website`.

We can retrofit the DXA Publications with our older BluePrint (except `400 Example Website`, of course), which would mean that we are just renaming some of the DXA Publications.

For content and Pages (if we need to reuse), I may just use Content Porter.

Are there any WebDAV dependencies that I might break while we retrofit (rename)? Should I be aware of any known issues, which I might encounter? Any recommendations from past efforts of similar nature?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably worth reading this: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/installing-dxa-in-an-existing-tridion-publication-structure

Comment: Since my BP is more a placeholder, my case is even simpler. In short, can I just rename `100 Master` and `400 Example Website` after the import process is complete? Any known problems or issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like Harald's blog post (referred to by Nuno above). But note that the DXA import PowerShell script also supports importing into existing Publications (see the script's parameters).

```
Get-Help .\import.ps1 -detailed
```

Answer (score 1):

Harald's blog (as refrerred to by Nuno) already indicates the renaming of Publications after import works, and so does the information Rick is pointing to, but let me officially confirm in the form of an answer.

The Publication names used in DXA are just example names, not related to any functionality. You are free to update the Publication names, or even import its content in different Publications of an existing BluePrint.

As long as you keep the base Folder structure alive (some changes will even be acceptable, but are not advised), everything will simply work, provided all the necessary items are available in your website Publication.

Comment: It was evident from the responses and my tests. Thanks for officially putting it together in the form of an answer! :)